# Is there a NSNotification for objects that become first resoponder?

Tags: iphone, notifications, uitextfield, uikeyboard, first-responder

Is there a NSNotification for objects that become first responder.
Like NSNotification that give me the  UITextfield that cause the keyboard to pop up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification`, the textField that started editing is in notification's `object` property.

There're also `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` notifications

Comment: ```UIKeyboardWillShowNotification``` and ```UIKeyboardDidShowNotification``` will not be triggered if you have a hardware keyboard and the on screen keyboard will not be shown (tested on iOS 8).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have your view controller be a delegate to the UITextField. UITextFieldDelegate has a textFieldDidBeginEditing: method.

Answer (score -1):

No, But you could check it manually by using "IsFirstResponder" (BOOL)..
Can you explain a little bit more what you want to accomplish? Maybe there is a way to use another notification.